How to add page margins (border lines) to a latex document? Also how to increase the line width of the border
I have a document in latex in which I want to add borders. I have the following code to add borders to the page:
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}
\newlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}

\setlength{\PageFrameTopMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameBottomMargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameLeftMargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\PageFrameRightMargin}{1.5cm}

\makeatletter

\newlength{\Page@FrameHeight}
\newlength{\Page@FrameWidth}
\AddToShipoutPicture{
    \thinlines
    \setlength{\Page@FrameHeight}{\paperheight-\PageFrameTopMargin-\PageFrameBottomMargin}
    \setlength{\Page@FrameWidth}{\paperwidth-\PageFrameLeftMargin-\PageFrameRightMargin}
    \put(\strip@pt\PageFrameLeftMargin,\strip@pt\PageFrameTopMargin){
        \framebox(\strip@pt\Page@FrameWidth, \strip@pt\Page@FrameHeight){}}}`

\makeatother

This code shows as error at \AddToShipoutPicture part and \put part. Sometimes it works and when it does the margins I am getting using this code is very thin. I want to make it wider.

Welcome! Are you able to (1) complete your code so we have a complete but small example we can run to reproduce the problem? and (2) post the error by copy-pasting it into your question so we can see exactly what it is? I don't know if \AddToShipoutPicture works with current LaTeX, though I'd expect it to. But it might be better to use one of the newer methods if you don't need this to run on older LaTeX.

Like this?

(Frame s are on all pages)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[line width=1pt]   % <--- thicknes of border lines
        ([shift={(-1mm,1mm)}] current page text area.north west)
    rectangle
        ([shift={(1mm,-1mm)}] current page text area.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

 \lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}

